# Substitute text in excel

Tags: excel, replace, substitution

I have an excel worksheet and some of the cells contain an abbreviation such as SC, FEW, ... followed by a number. for example SC058 or FEW01, and some of the cells contain a combination of two or three of these, i.e. FEW004 SC044.
I would like to substitute each of the abbreviations regardless of the number that is attached to them by a value. For examples I want all the "FEW004, FEW056,..." to be replaced by number "5" and etc.

Since the database is huge, any suggestion on how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: If the abbreviation are not too varied (say, start with only "S", "F" and "C", then a regular search and replace with wildcards (e.g, "F*", "S?????") might be sufficient. If not, can go to more complicated string parsing or regex approach.

Comment: This would replace the whole cell. For example the cell that contains SCT022 BLK038 would all be replaced by a single value

Comment: Just trying to figure out your data. Something like "SC???" or "FEW???" wouldn't replace the whole cell, but then again you may have way too many possible alpha codes to deal with by hand. Are you interest in a regex approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a quick sample that would do one type of substitution (your example of changing anything with "FEW" to "5"), hopefully it is of some use:

```
Sub substitute_abb()

theData = ActiveCell.Value
theNewData = ""

theDataArray = Split(theData, " ")

For Each x In theDataArray
    If InStr(x, "FEW") Then
        newSegment = "5"
        Else
        newSegment = x
    End If
    If theNewData = "" Then
        theNewData = newSegment
        Else
        theNewData = theNewData & " " & newSegment
    End If
Next

ActiveCell.Value = theNewData

End Sub
```

I realise for the split delimiter you might want ", " rather than just " " and then on the theNewData composition again maybe you'd want ", ". And of course, this would need expanding to other substitutions. Is this a good start?